# Possible to refresh user control?

Tags: c#

If I have done a user control and then update it by moving around a button or size of a panel, I noticed it's still the old version on the windows form. And when I delete it and drag it out from the toolbox again, it's still the old one!

Is there a way to refresh the user controls or do I have to start from the beginning and make a new?

Comment: Have you tried to close the designer? Sometimes Clean Solution and Rebuild do magic as well.

Comment: Try closing the designer window for the control form that hosts your user control, then re-open it.

Comment: You need to build. The designer is taking the user control from the dll/exe, run it and show the result in the form.

Comment: Erno, your comment helped! Thanks!